# React Native promise and queue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a localization in my project; and before calling the component, I want to call the setI18nConfig () method, which is responsible for languages.
But when I call it, the component is processed first, and then this method.
That is, this method becomes the last in the queue. I think this is because of the promise.
But what can affect the problem to solve it

**App.js**

```
import {setI18nConfig} from './src/localesConfig';
import StackNavigator from './src/routes/homeStack';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    setI18nConfig(); // <---- here
  }

  render() {
    return (StackNavigator());
  }
}
```

**localesConfig.js**

```
export async function getCurrentLanguage() {
  try {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem('Language');
  } catch (e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}

export const translationGetters = {
  // lazy requires (metro bundler does not support symlinks)
  en: () => require('./translations/en.json'),
  ru: () => require('./translations/ru.json'),
};

export const setI18nConfig = () => {
  i18n.missingTranslation = function(key) {
    return key;
  };
  // fallback if no available language fits
  const fallback = {languageTag: 'en', isRTL: false};

  const isRTL = fallback.isRTL;
  getCurrentLanguage().then(val => { //<----here quee
    const languageTag = val || fallback.languageTag;
    // clear translation cache
    translate.cache.clear();
    // update layout direction
    I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
    // set i18n-js config
    i18n.translations = {[languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]()};
    i18n.locale = languageTag;
  });
```

**homeBottomTabs.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{translate('password')}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }export default function RootTab() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      tabBarOptions={{
        tabStyle: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        showIcon: false,
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{title: translate('Menu:Home'), headerShown: false}}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={{title: translate('Menu:Chat'), headerShown: false}}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And when the Main screen is called (that is, when the application starts), as a result I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clAAP.png), but it should be like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqQm.png)

Comment: My solution to this problem was to set a "isReady" boolean state variable and render the app only when all translations/locales are loaded. This will prevent flash-ing of keys but will increase the "white screen" time (usually it's not that long anyway).

Comment: @TsvetanGanev thanks a lot of, works good!